# Disable any API exposed by flask-security

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I was trying to implement login functionality in my app. I started with using flask-security for basic api exposed by flask-security like `register, login, logout` etc.

While doing this, I realised that some of the API's provided by `flask-security` is not of my use. So for that, I was looking to disable some of the API but didn't get anything related to that.

I saw [flask-security-config](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/configuration.html) too, but there is no way to disable API which is exposed by flask-security.

I am new to [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/) & [flask-security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) & struggled a lot but didn't get sucess. Any useful suggestion will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the way to do this.

Follow this link: [flask security config](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/configuration.html#feature-flags) to disable API's which you don't want to keep in your application.

Comment: This is a link-only answer… and the link in question is just the scheme!

Comment: @NickK9: It's always nice to improve the answer rather than criticizing and downvoting it. Hope you understand :)

Comment: Guys, it was a broken link, which I have fixed now. Go through it once, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, you can disable the default flask-security blueprint during the Security object init `app.security = Security(app, user_datastore, register_blueprint=False)`.